# round off compute AVG to 2 decimal places in SQL query

Tags: sql

COMPUTE AVG label 'Rating' OF feedbackRating ON houseID

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to enrich the question with details about tables, your current code and details on the task if you want to allow people understand what you're in need of.